# How to change in text before saving webpage as a picture

Tags: puppeteer-sharp

Is it possible with Puppeteersharp to render text, and highlight words that match specific criteria, before saving the webpage as a picture?

In order to save the webpage as html and then do the work, adds others problems (links to picture etc..)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `page.evaluate` like so:

```
await page.evaluate(() => {
    const pTags = document.getElementsByTagName("p")
    for (let i=0;i<pTags.length-1;i++){
       pTags[i].style.background="red"
     }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I can't make it work that way.  I think i got a working solution.  string content = await page.GetContentAsync();  . Then use Replace.